# Number of connections on unix socket

Tags: c, sockets, unix, posix, unix-socket

Given an arbritary unix socket address, am I able to get the number of connections on it via a POSIX api call?

Or would I have to walk though the /proc filesystem?

Comment: You should clarify 'arbitrary unix socket address'; given the tags, you probably mean 'arbitrary Unix domain socket', rather than 'an arbitrary socket address on a Unix machine'.  There's a comment below that indicates you are using Cygwin too, which suggests a Windows host.

Comment: Yep, that is what I meant, 'arbitrary Unix domain socket'. I said POSIX, as opposed to cygwin, because I wanted to keep any possible solution the problem as cross platform as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume you mean the number of current connections on a port, not the total connection count over the lifetime of a socket fd which was my first thought. I'm afraid the most portable method is popen("netstat -n", "r") and try to parse it. POSIX gives us very little in the area of system/network administration tools.

Comment: Yep, I just need the current num of connections on a unix domain socket. Unfortunately my target system is cygwun and netstat isn't available on it as a package nor does the source compile. Hence I was hoping for an API call that would give me the info.

Comment: How are you acquiring the Unix domain socket? From a program that you've written? I don't believe you will find a simple single API call that will do what you want. *But* it is possible with a handful of function calls etc if we know the context... More details will be required @rhlee

Comment: @Jim Norton: Basically I'm using/modifying dtach on cygwin. Dtach uses named bsd sockets for master/slave communication and hence the namespace for sessions. If dtach terminates unexpectedly the socket is still left, so you do not know if the session is still running. I think effectively what I'm trying is lsof the socket which doesn't work http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.admin/2003-12/0019.html . Going to give Alan the answer as it doesn't look as if there is any real way to do it. However you did mention some function calls? Would much appreciate if you could elaborate Jim.